I can't synchronize data from v-treeview
In my Nuxt 3.13.0 project I have a v-treeview. I want the data from the node selected by the user to be synchronised to "activeNodes":
<template>
  <v-col v-if="treePopulated" cols="7" class="pa-0">
    <v-treeview
      activatable
      :active.sync="activeNodes"
      color="#965F1A"
      hoverable
      :items="certificatesTree"
      dense
   />
  <button @click="buttonPressed">Here</button>
  </v-col>
</template>

<script setup>
 const activeNodes = ref(["Initial value"]);
 const treePopulated = ref(false);
   
 const certificatesTree = ref([
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Cars',
        children: [
          { id: 11, title: 'Chevrolet', children: [{id: 111, title: "Chev Model 1"}, 
                                                   {id: 112, title: "Chev Model 2"}] },
          { id: 12, title: 'Ford', children: [{id: 121, title: "Ford Model 1"}, 
                                              {id: 122, title: "Ford Model 2"}] },
          {
            id: 13,
            title: 'Mazda',
            children: [{id: 131,title: "Mazda Model 1"}, 
                       {id: 132,title: "Mazda Model 2"}],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Bikes',
        children: [
          { id: 21, title: 'AKT', children: [{id: 211,title: "AKT Model 1"}, 
                                             {id: 212,title: "AKT Model 2"}] },
          { id: 22, title: 'BMW', children: [{id: 221,title: "BMW Model 1"}, 
                                             {id: 223,title: "BMW Model 2"}] },
          {
            id: 23,
            title: 'Yamaha',
            children: [{id: 231,title: "Yamaha Model 1"}, 
                       {id: 232,title: "Yamaha Model 2"}],
          },
        ],
      },
    ]);

    function getFullTree() {
       //Get data from api and add to tree
       treePopulated.value = true;
       return certificatesTree.value
    }

function buttonPressed(){
      console.log("ActiveNodes")
      console.log(activeNodes.value);
    }
</script>

The problem is that the value of activeNodes is not updated, as the console always logs "initial value". Vuetify version is 3.7.1 btw.

Looks like you are using v2 syntax with v3 Vue/Vuetify. The sync modifier (in :active.sync) was removed in v3 in favor of extended v-model syntax (i.e.v-model:active, see migration guide). Also, it is activated now.
